# Toolbar at the bottom not showing

Tags: iphone, toolbar

I used the xcode4 xib file to design the following UI:

```
View
   Table View
   Toolbar
      Bar Button Item
         Segmented Control
      Bar Button Item 
         Segmented Control
```

On the design sheet, both Table View and Toolbar show up; but when I run the app in simulator, the toolbar is not showing up.

I tried to make the table view invisible (as a test) and to bring the toolbar to the front. Still the toolbar does not show.

Do you have any idea what I might be doing wrong, and what I should try next? Do I need to do init for the toolbar in the .m file?

Thanks much!

Lu

Answer (score 2):

Have you set the the `toolbarHidden` property of your `UINavigationController`to `NO` ? You have to explicitly do this to show the toolbar as it is defaulty set to YES.  If this isn't the issue, we need to see some code, especially your toolbar initialization and etc.

Comment: Thanks, Jesse! I thought by adding the toolbar through the NIB file, I can get away from initializing the toolbar. Could you give me a pointer to what need to be initialized in addition to the NIB config? Do I have to grammatically initialize the segmentControl, UIBarButtonItem, toolbarItems and toolbar, etc?